# How to extend views to max width?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using react-native-modal in my project on Expo.

But, actually this modal has some space between modal and frame of device.
I tried to set width: '100%' but that didn't work.

Do someone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you,

Comment: Check if your View wrapper tag has 100% width on it, not only in the component itself but also in the parent if it has some.

Comment: Yes, I did. I set width: '100%' to all of components.

Comment: Might want to try changing 100% to 100vw.

Comment: This needs more detail in order to be solvable.  Can you post the code in question, or a JSFiddle so users can see what the problem is?